# DFA Rejection State

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I'm being asked to construct a DFA for the language over $\{0,1\}$ such that each string of five consecutive symbols contain at least two zeroes. In my construction, it seems to me that it would make it easier if I could simply lead invalid strings to a "rejection state".

My question is whether such a "rejection state" is accepted convention: I am imagining something like this:

[image]

Where $q_3$ is the final, or accepting state, and $\emptyset$ is simply a state that denotes that the DFA rejects the string. Is such a "rejecting state" acceptable to write? Is it conventional? Any other thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DFA's don't usually have "reject" states.  But you can model these by so-called "sink" states: states which, once entered, you can never leave. What transitions from your $\varnothing$ state can you think of that will turn it into a sink?

Comment: Are you saying that the DFA simply 'dies', i.e. has to reject the input, if it arrives at a non-accepting state, out of which there are no transitions?

Comment: For example, say the DFA arrives at some $q_n$, which has only one outgoing transition on a symbol $a$. Suppose the DFA then reads some symbol $x \neq a$. The DFA then rejects the input, correct? Suppose the DFA reads $x \neq a$, and after that, it reads an $a$. The DFA then still rejects the input, right?

Comment: @Newb: DFAs are defined so that the transition function is total: for _every_ state $q$ and _every_ input letter $x$ the value $\delta (q,x)$ is defined to be a single state. But there is no demand that $\delta(q,x)$ is different from $q$.  (NFAs, however, can have "death states": since the range of the transition function is the family of _subsets_ (not necessarily nonempty) of the set of states.)

Comment: Arthur, please answer my questions from my earlier comment "For example, say (...) input, right?": they are quite important to me. I must make sure that I've understood this correctly. Thank You!

Comment: @Newb: I think my above comment addresses this: by definition the transition function of a DFA _must_ be total: defined for _every_ state and _every_ input symbol. What you are describing is _not_ a DFA (although the idea you have can be modeled by a DFA using these sink states).

Comment: @Newb: Arthur really has answered your question in the earlier comment, but I’ll make it very explicit: no, that’s not right, because what you’ve described is not a DFA. (It’s actually a kind of NFA.) A DFA must by definition have a transition out of each state for each symbol of the input alphabet. Your picture does not show a DFA, because the automaton that it shows has no $a$-transition and no $b$-transition out of state $\varnothing$ or out of state $q_3$.